# PyQt5 Run function after displaying window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to call a function after the GUI displays. If I run function in **init** it prevents gui from displaying until after it is completed.

```
class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.function() #waits for this to finish until gui displayed
    def function(self):
        self.guiBox.setValue(initData)
        #inits stuff, takes 5 seconds
```

The function initializes a piece of equipment via serial port... It takes s few seconds, and it takes gui attributes and updates gui display boxes.

Comment: you should say more about what the function is doing, do you need it inside the main window (does it refer to some attributes) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time-consuming tasks are blocking, and this goes against the natural way of working on the GUI, an option is to use `qApp.processEvents()`, for example:

```
def function(self):
    self.guiBox.setValue(initData)
    code1
    QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()
    code2
    QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()
    ...
```

Comment: That does the exact opposite of what I need. I want to the GUI to display first, then run the function.

Comment: That worked nicely, thanks! I will accept as answer in a few days if no one else poses a better solution.

Comment: It could give a much better solution if the function is known.

Comment: I think a better solution would be one that is independent of what goes on in function... I should be able to use function() or function2() and not have to explicitly process gui events in each. My function opens serial connection, sends command, then reads data, and displays data to GUI in spinbox.

Comment: I understand what you are searching for, is that the best solution for me is the one that performs the task with the least amount of resources (memory and / or time). :P

Comment: Another way is using QThreads, but I see it unnecessary in your case.

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 5):

Add single shot timer 1 ms and after call function

```
  class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
      QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
      Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
      self.setupUi(self)
      QTimer.singleShot(1,self.function) #waits for this to finish until gui displayed
    def function(self):
      self.guiBox.setValue(initData)
      #inits stuff, takes 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend QThreads, especially if you are performing a ton of other actions in your "function." This example isn't the only way to thread in PyQt, but thought an example where you are able to pass data back and forth between the thread and the main gui would be best.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QEventLoop, QThread, QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class time_consuming_function(QObject):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super(time_consuming_function, self).__init__()
        self.widget = widget
        self.run_trigger.connect(self.run)

    run_trigger = pyqtSignal(int, int)
    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def run(self, int1, int2):
        print("In Time Consuming Function")
        for i in range(100000000):
            i*i
        print("Finished with Time Consuming Function")
        self.widget.someTrigger.emit([1, 2, 3])

class WebPage(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
        self.load(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)

        self.someTrigger.connect(self.gui_response)

        self.thread = QThread()
        self.thread.start()
        self.consume = time_consuming_function(self)
        self.consume.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.consume.run_trigger.emit(1,1)

    someTrigger = pyqtSignal(list)

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        print("Finished Loading")

    def gui_response(self, data):
        print("Responding to GUI: ", str(data))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = WebPage()
    web.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest way without using thread and related would be to verify if the last event of showing up the window was executed and then call your method.

---

You'd have something like that:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        self.move(300, 50)

    def print_1_bi(self):
        for i in range(10**9): print(i)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.InputMethodQuery:
            self.print_1_bi()
        return super(MainWindow, self).event(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Note:** *Remember that even though the UI already showed up your application will be waiting your method to finish, if it's a problem you'll have to use process like the guys told you to in the other answers.*